# Tip: How to avoid opening "Issue Navigator" in Xcode4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

It really annoyed me, that every time an error was raised, when running a build in XCode4, the left sidebar swapped to "Issue Navigator" tab. And every time you had to click on "Project Navigator" to get back to the class file hierarchy. (as the console output is more useful to me for debugging.)

How does one avoid opening "Issue Navigator" in Xcode4 when a error is encountered in a project in Xcode?

Comment: You could post it as question and answer; I don't know if someone (well, no-a-real-question-police) will be mad at you when you posting it this way, with an answer in the question..

Answer (score 27):

Try in Xcode selecting from the **Xcode** Menu>> **Preferences** >> choose **Behavioirs** Tab >> choose **Build generates new issues** >> change behavior in **"Show navigator"** section.